# Unable to set the FormulaArray of the Range Class -- Less than 255, not using replace method

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error

all:

I feel like this is something painfully obvious but I have been banging my head up against the wall for a while and can't seem to find a solution.

When entering the below formula into "M3"

```
=IFERROR(IF(ISBLANK(VLOOKUP(A3&"|"&E3,CHOOSE({1,2},OLD_PR!$A$3:$A$374&"|"&OLD_PR!$E$3:$E$374,OLD_PR!$O$3:$O$374),2,FALSE)),"",VLOOKUP(A3&"|"&E3,CHOOSE({1,2},OLD_PR!$A$3:$A$374&"|"&OLD_PR!$E$3:$E$374,OLD_PR!$O$3:$O$374),2,FALSE)),"")
```

with this code (ActiveCell = "M3")

```
ActiveCell.FormulaArray = _
        "=IFERROR(IF(ISBLANK(VLOOKUP(A3&" & Chr(34) & "|" & Chr(34) & "&E3,CHOOSE({1,2},OLD_PR!$A$3:$A$" & OldPRLastRow & "&" & Chr(34) & "|" & Chr(34) & "&OLD_PR!$E$3:$E$" & OldPRLastRow & ",OLD_PR!$O$3:$O$" & OldPRLastRow & "),2,FALSE)),""""," _
        & "VLOOKUP(A3&" & Chr(34) & "|" & Chr(34) & "&E3,CHOOSE({1,2},OLD_PR!$A$3:$A$" & OldPRLastRow & "&" & Chr(34) & "|" & Chr(34) & "&OLD_PR!$E$3:$E$" & OldPRLastRow & ",OLD_PR!$O$3:$O$" & OldPRLastRow & "),2,FALSE))," _
        & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & ")"
```

I am getting the Run-time error in the title.

1. When I manually enter the formula, it works.
2. The formula is less than 255 characters without the replace work around, so I'm not making any mistakes there
3. I'm only entering the formula into a single cell

The above are the most common mistakes I found via google searches, but do not apply to me. I'm sure this is something silly.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I entered the formula with `OldPRLastRow = 50` and it didn't give me any error. What are the error code and description? What is the value of `OldPRLastRow`? Have you checked it has the appropriate value?

Comment: @SuperSymmetry I just double checked and 374 is indeed the correct value. The exact error message I am getting is "Run-time error '1004': Unable to set the FormulaArray property of the Range class"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With reference to [this](https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/long-array-vba-issue.853889/) try

```
    ActiveCell.FormulaArray = _
        "=IFERROR(IF(ISBLANK(VLOOKUP(D3&" & Chr(34) & "|" & Chr(34) & "&E3,""ChoosePart"",2,FALSE)),""""," _
        & "VLOOKUP(D3&" & Chr(34) & "|" & Chr(34) & "&E3,""ChoosePart"",2,FALSE))," _
        & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & ")"
    
    ActiveCell.Replace """ChoosePart""", "CHOOSE({1,2},OLD_PR!$A$3:$A$" & OldPRLastRow & "&" & Chr(34) & "|" & Chr(34) & "&OLD_PR!$E$3:$E$" & OldPRLastRow & ",OLD_PR!$O$3:$O$" & OldPRLastRow & ")"
```

Comment: Thank you for the post! Unfortunately this didn't work for me either. I guess I was misunderstanding the length requirement? I was assuming the character requirement is on the whatever you are assigning to the .FormulaArray and *not* just the end formula (i.e. whatever ends up in the cell)?

Answer (score 0):

Since Column O contains text values, here's an alternative...

```
ActiveCell.FormulaArray = "=LOOKUP(REPT(""z"",255),CHOOSE({1,2},"""",INDEX(OLD_PR!$O$3:$O$" & OldPRLastRow & ",MATCH(A3&""|""&E3,OLD_PR!$A$3:$A$" & OldPRLastRow & "&""|""&OLD_PR!$E$3:$E$" & OldPRLastRow & ",0))))"
```

Comment: By the way, what type of value does Column O contain, text value or numerical value?

Comment: Thanks for the tip on VLOOKUP; unfornuately using Formula/Formula2 does not work. Column O contains a string.

Comment: Since it looks like the issue turned out to be the character limit, I have deleted my original post, and I have posted an alternative solution.